# Method overloading by generic where clause in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, factory

Is it possible to overload a method in C# with a generic where clause?

Below I have a factory which can create car part objects. There is a very generic Create-method in the factory but two specific too. The problem is know that the two specific ones has the same method signature except the where clause.

The compiler does not allow the method declaration but the code in the main-method works (if I press 'F12->GoToDefinition' then the correct method is found).

```cs
public interface ICarPart { }

public class CommonPart : ICarPart { }
public class Engine : ICarPart { }
public class Gear : ICarPart { }

public interface IFactory
{
    T Create<T>();
    T Create<T>(int arg) where T : Engine;
    T Create<T>(int arg) where T : Gear; // <- Problem
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main(IFactory factory)
    {
        var commonPart = factory.Create<CommonPart>();
        var engine = factory.Create<Engine>(4);
        var gear = factory.Create<Gear>(4); <- Working
    }
}
```

Is there a nice way to write a factory api like this which has a good compiler support? It feels that I am near, but some detail is missing.

Of course I can give each method an individual name but that is not sexy.

Comment: Seems like an anti pattern what you're trying to do. Usually a factory is good at creating only one thing.

Comment: No, you cannot overload based on generic type constraints. Aim for clear code, rather than sexy code

Comment: There is a _really bad way_ around this: optional parameters.